# MATLAB GUI Error while using set

Tags: matlab

why I cant have the output in the edit text?

```
% --- Executes on button press in f.
function f_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to f (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
clc
syms t
a=str2double(get(handles.b1,'string'));
b=str2double(get(handles.c1,'string'));
y=eval(get(handles.a1,'string'));
u=a-b;
m=abs(y).^2;
r=int(m,t);
g1=subs(r,t,a);
h=subs(r,t,b);
fh=g1-h;
s=fh./u
set(handles.e,'string',s)';
```

Command window shows the answer not edit text.The error is:
    Error using set
    error: mxArray must be double, char, or cell

```
Error in signalproject2>f_Callback (line 284)
set(handles.e,'string',s)';

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
    feval(varargin{:});

Error in signalproject2 (line 42)
gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)signalproject2('f_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

Can u  please help me with this?

Comment: How do you define `handles.e` ?

Comment: @P0W: this looks like a GUI generated by GUIDE, so it's likely the tag for the editbox UI element.

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of `s`? Use `whos s` to find out.

If it's not a double, char, or cell then you won't be able to assign it as a string for your edit box. This is exactly what the error message tells you.

I don't have the symbolic math toolbox so I can't check the code, but I'm guessing `s` is a symbolic array. If this is the case, see the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/char.html) for `char` to convert the symbolic array to a string so you can assign it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Could it simply be because there is a ' you don't want at the end of this line:

```
set(handles.e,'string',s)';
```

what if you try:

```
set(handles.e,'string',s);
```